# nodejs lambda async handle don't finished after await function

Tags: node.js, lambda

I am creating a simple lambda function that connects with documentdb.

serverless.yml

```yaml
# ...
functions:
  helloWorld:
    handler: src/handlers/helloWorld.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get
```

src\handlers\helloWorld.js

```js
"use strict";

const { mongoClient } = require("../helpers/dbHelper");

module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const db = await mongoClient();
    const data = await db.collection("mytable").find({}).toArray();

    console.log(data);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: "hello world" }),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

The `data` variable is correctly queried and the return function works as expected, but the function just doesn't finish, until timeout.

If I put the hardcoded return above the `mongoClient()`, the function will finish as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it missed the vpc config

```yaml
provider:
  # ...
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxx
      - subnet-xxxxxxxxxx
      - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```